# Why does the colour inside a discharge tube change as pressure reduces?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Observing cathode ray tubes at various pressures, I see a transition from a violet/purple colour at 10-40mmHg, transition to a white/light blue colour at lower pressures.

Any idea why this happens?

It doesn't seem like it is the glass itself fluorescing as the glow continues to weaken at even lower pressures.

A video can be found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioSiSA9spfQ

At 1:15 - see pink glow
At 1:50 - lower pressure, white glow.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: My first thought is when the pressure is increased you get more energy transfer due to the increased probability of collision

Comment: I don't see how that would cause it to change colour. I am assuming that both of the tubes have the same gas in them.

Answer (score 1):

run image through spectrum analysis, My leaning is  the brighter colors are washed out at lower intensities, even seeing into the infrared is not unknown, so at the ultraviolet side some may not even see the shift